# How to handle json_array type with formbuilder in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

In Symfony form has not to Type for `json_array` like (EntityType, TextType). So I need to store `json_array` in DB column with work in new and edit. Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: Why not just use TextType to store your json ?

Comment: Yes, right But how can manage easily in Edit operation?

Comment: It depend on what you want to store and what data you are encoding in json. Why would you need a "JsonType" in your form ?

Comment: In form, I have one filed where user can select multiple options. I have to store child table keys in json_array in a single column.

Comment: So you could just get this array in your controller and set it manually with json_encode after the isValid part of your controller ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new Form Type with all the data you want to store as json array in your entity. By default, if no `data_class` is defined the forms will return the data as (associative) array with the keys being the field names and the properties being the values. If you place this data in your entity's property which will be persisted as json_array, it should work right away.

See also: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html